# Knockout foreach binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a problem to show different content for different `datetime` with knockout `foreach` binding.

Everything is working good, but a major problem is with the functions `showData` and `getDataByCurrentDate`

I created some example code to show what I'm trying to do:

This is my JavaScript code:

```
       var data = { "Blog": [
         {
           "date":"07/09/2012",
           "title":"Title 1",
           "content":"Text 1"
         },
         {
           "date":"08/09/2012",
           "title":"Title 2",
           "content":"Text 2"
         },
         {
           "date":"09/09/2012",
           "title":"Title 3",
           "content":"Text 3"
          },
          {
           "date":"10/09/2012",
           "title":"Title 4",
           "content":"Text 4"
          }      
         ]
       };

       var current = new Date();

       function formatCurrentDate() {
         return ('0' + current.getDate()).slice(-2) + '/' + ('0' + (current.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '/' + current.getFullYear();
       }

       function getDataByCurrentDate() {
         var output = [];
         for(var i in data.Blog) {
           if(data.Blog[i].date== formatCurrentDate()) {
             output.push(data.Blog[i]);
           }
         }
         return output;
       }

       function showData(data) {
         var output = 'No data';
         if(data.length > 0) {
           for(var i in data) {
             self.findDataBlog.push(data1[x]); 
           }
         }
       }
       function loadData() {
         var data = getDataByCurrentDate();
         showData(data);
         showCurrentDate();
       }

       function showCurrentDate() {
         document.getElementById('currentDate').innerHTML = formatCurrentDate();
       }

       window.onload = function() {
         loadData();

         document.getElementById('next').onclick = function() {
           current.setTime(current.getTime() + 1000*60*60*24);
           loadData();
           return false;
         }

         document.getElementById('previous').onclick = function() {
           current.setTime(current.getTime() - 1000*60*60*24);
           loadData();
           return false;
         }
       }
```

This is the `body` tag:

```
        <a href="#" id="previous"> << </a>  
        <span id="currentDate"></span>
        <a href="#" id="next"> >> </a>

        <div data-bind="foreach: findDataBlog">
          <ul>
            <li>
             <a>
              <h1><span data-bind="text: title"></span></h1>
              <p>
                <span data-bind="date: date"></span>
                <span data-bind="text: content"></span>
              </p>
             </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
       </div>
```

Comment: It's difficult to provide an answer withour knowing what the problem is... what error are you getting exactly? what output did you expect and what did you get?

Comment: btw, _data1_ doesn't seem to be defined anywhere, but you add elements from it to an array _self.findDataBlog_ (of which we don't see the definitions either, though i can guess self is this and findDataBlog an (observable?) array) - is this a typo or may be the source of the problem?

Comment: What is the problem? You need to post more of your javascript code, and actually explain what the problem is.

Comment: ok I create page on http://jsfiddle.net/marko4286/cZCdb/4

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: data1 is not defined `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a working jsFiddle for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/ruslans/Y58DJ/

The main changes I've made is introduced a knockout `viewModel` variable and fixed errors in `showData()` function:

```
var myViewModel = {
    findDataBlog = ko.observableArray();
}

ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);

...

function showData(data) {
    myViewModel.findDataBlog.removeAll()
    if (data.length > 0) {
        for (var i in data) {
            myViewModel.findDataBlog.push(data[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

amended html:

```
<a href="#" id="previous"> << </a><span id="currentDate"></span>
<a href="#" id="next"> >> </a>

<br />
<span data-bind="visible: findDataBlog().length == 0">no data</span>
<div data-bind="foreach: findDataBlog, visible: findDataBlog().length > 0">
    <ul>
        <li> <a>
              <h1><span data-bind="text: title"></span></h1>
              <p>
                <span data-bind="date: date"></span>
                <span data-bind="text: content"></span>
              </p>
             </a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: your example is good, but how to disable duplicates (try to use left and right arrow and back to date with data)

Comment: cool. I've updated my answer accordingly. Feel free to accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    //findDataBlog should be declare as observable array.

    var findDataBlog = ko.observableArray(); 

   // Please try with this.
```

Comment: yes I put that, I didnt't mention I put that at the begining of script.. I think the problem is where I call showData, because I always get data for one day...